# How to identify a store as Auto, Restaurant, Medical, etc? SwfitUI | Firebase

Tags: firebase, swiftui

I would like to identify an entry as either a restaurant, auto, medical, etc using a picker option.  This is not my own code, I am following Jeff Gaullaugher's course on Snacktacular.

When a user enters a new Store, I want them to be able to add a category to that Store entry.  I have googled relentlessly; confused and I know there will be an easy way to add this, but at a loss.

Using Firebase.  Thank you for any suggestions.

```
STORE MODEL:
struct Store: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var name = ""
    var address = ""
    var latitude = 0.0
    var longitude = 0.0
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    }
    
    var dictionary: [String: Any] {
        return ["name": name, "address": address,"latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude]
    }
}


 DETAIL VIEW
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
       
                  TextField("Name", text: $store.name)
                      .font(Font.system(size:15, design: .rounded))
                      .lineLimit(1)
                  TextField("Address", text: $store.address)
                      .font(Font.system(size:15, design: .rounded))
              }
              .disabled(store.id == nil ? false : true)
              .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
              .padding(.horizontal)
            
            
            Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion, showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: annotations) { annotation in
                MapMarker(coordinate: annotation.coordinate)
            }
            .frame(height: 250)
            .onChange(of: store) { _ in
                annotations = [Annotation(name: store.name, address: store.address, coordinate: store.coordinate)]
                mapRegion.center = store.coordinate
            }
            
      
            
            HStack {
                Group {
                    Text("Avg. Rating")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                    Text(avgRating)
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                }
                .lineLimit(1)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    if store.id == nil {
                        showSaveAlert.toggle()
                    } else {
                        showReviewViewSheet.toggle()
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Image(Image(systemName: "hand.thumbsup"))
                    Text("Rate")
                })
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                .bold()
                .tint(Color.blue)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(reviews) { review in
                        NavigationLink {
                            ReviewView(store: store, review: review)
                        } label: {
                            ReviewRowView(review: review)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .headerProminence(.increased)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
            if !previewRunning && store.id != nil { // This is to prevent PreviewProvider error
                $reviews.path = "stores/\(store.id ?? "")/reviews"
                print("reviews.path = \($reviews.path)")
                
            } else { // store.id starts out as nil
                showingAsSheet = true
            }
            
            if store.id != nil { // If we have a store, center map on the store
                mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: store.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionSize, longitudinalMeters: regionSize)
            } else { // otherwise center the map on the device location
                Task { // If you don't embed in a Task, the map update likely won't show
                    mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationManager.location?.coordinate ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D(), latitudinalMeters: regionSize, longitudinalMeters: regionSize)
                }
            }
            annotations = [Annotation(name: store.name, address: store.address, coordinate: store.coordinate)]
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(store.id == nil)
        .toolbar {
            if showingAsSheet { // New store, so show Cancel / Save buttons
                if store.id == nil && showingAsSheet { // New store, so show Cancel/Save buttons
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                        Button("Cancel") {
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Save") {
                            Task {
                                let success = await storeVM.saveStore(store: store)
                                if success {
                                    dismiss()
                                } else {
                                    print(" DANG! Error saving store!")
                                }
                            }
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Button {
                            showPlaceLookupSheet.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            Text("Lookup Place")
                        }
                        
                    }
                } else if showingAsSheet && store.id != nil {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button("Done") {
                            dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPlaceLookupSheet) {
            PlaceLookupView(store: $store)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showReviewViewSheet) {
            NavigationStack {
                ReviewView(store: store, review: Review())
            }
        }
        .alert("Cannot Rate Place Unless It is Saved", isPresented: $showSaveAlert) {
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
            Button("Save", role: .none) {
                Task {
                    let success = await storeVM.saveStore(store: store)
                    store = storeVM.store
                    if success {
                        // If we didn't update the path after saving store, we wouldn't be able to show new reviews added
                        $reviews.path = "stores/\(store.id ?? "")/reviews"
                        
                        
                    } else {
                        print(" Dang! Error saving store!")
                    }
                }
            }
        } message: {
            Text("Would you like to save this alert first so that you can enter a review?")
        }
    }
    
}
    struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                DetailView(store: Store(), previewRunning: true)
                    .environmentObject(StoreViewModel())
                    .environmentObject(LocationManager())
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is the issue? What have you tried? What did work and what didn´t? Try to be more specific.